# passport serialize user into session

Tags: node.js, authentication, passport.js

I'm getting this error when trying to login to my app:

Error: Failed to serialize user into session

The problem is that it is reading parameter user.id as undefined. If I change it to the id value the user has in the database login works.

```
passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
        done(null, user.id);
});
```

Any ideas on why am I getting my user value as undefined?

pasport local login:

```
    // =========================================================================
    // LOCAL LOGIN =============================================================
    // =========================================================================
    passport.use(
        'local-login',
        new LocalStrategy({
            usernameField : 'username',
            passwordField : 'password',
            passReqToCallback : true // allows us to pass back the entire request to the callback
        },
        function(req, username, password, done) {
            if(username == "" || password == ""){
                return done(null, false, req.flash('loginMessage', 'Please fill in all blank fields to login.'));
            }else{
                query.login(req, username, password, done);
            }
        })
    );
```

login query:

```
    login: function(req, username, password, done) {
        connection.query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = ?",[username], function(err, rows){
            if (err)
                return done(err);
            if (!rows.length)
                return done(null, false, req.flash('loginMessage', 'Sorry, username/password do not match.')); // req.flash is the way to set flashdata using connect-flash

            // if the user is found but the password is wrong
            if (!bcrypt.compareSync(password, rows[0].password))
                return done(null, false, req.flash('loginMessage', 'Sorry, username/password do not match.')); // create the loginMessage and save it to session as flashdata

            // all is well, return successful user
            return done(null, rows[0]);
        });
    }
```

Login was working until I changed some field names on my database but I updated all my queries with the new names of the fields so I do not know whats happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out the problem. Since I changed the field name of id to id_users on my database the serializeUser function goes like this:

```
    passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
        done(null, user.id_users);
    });
```